# Get this error when I run my pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I got a problem with my pgfcodes. I get this error:

> ! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, pgfplots expects stacked plots to have exactly
>   the same number of coordinates. Unfortunately, I encountered at plot with DIFF
>   ERENT NUMBERS OF COORDINATES. Please verify that 1. no point has been dropped b
>   y coordinate filters (for example log(0) or so) and 2. all plots have the same
>   number of coordinates..

I can't find out what I'm doing wrong. The code is generated from matlab2tikz and it is a stacked barplot.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
view={0}{90},
width=6cm,
height=4cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=0, xmax=7,
xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6},
xticklabels={Volsted,Sønderholm,Lundby Bakker,Hals Nørreskov,Vester Aslund,Branths},
x tick label style={
    rotate=60,anchor=east},
ymin=0, ymax=12,
ylabel={Antal data},
ymajorgrids,
title={Antal data},
axis lines*=left,
legend style={align=left},
ybar stacked,
bar width=0.342857142857143cm,
area legend]
\addplot[fill=green,draw=black] plot coordinates{ (1,8) (2,5) (3,7) (4,2) (5,0) (6,7) };

\addlegendentry{Boringer};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
coordinates{
(0,0)(7,0) 
};
\addplot[fill=blue,draw=black] plot coordinates{ (1,3) (2,3) (3,3) (4,0) (5,3) (6,3) };

\addlegendentry{Vandværk};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

My document is in danish writing and I am a danish myself, so don't bother if you can't understand :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not use only two points (in your case `(0,0) (7,0)`) since you are using six bars. For example, I'm using here

```
\addplot[fill=green,draw=black] plot coordinates{ (1,8) (2,5) (3,7) (4,2) (5,3) (6,7) };
\addlegendentry{Green color};

\addplot[fill=red,solid,
%forget plot
]
coordinates{ (1,2) (2,2)  (3,5) (4,1) (5,3) (6,4) };
\addlegendentry{Red color};

\addplot[fill=cyan,draw=black] plot coordinates{ (1,3) (2,3) (3,3) (4,0) (5,3) (6,3) };
\addlegendentry{Cyan color};
```

and the result is

[image]

Comment: So instead of (0,0) (7,0) I can add these?: (1,2) (2,2)  (3,5) (4,1) (5,3) (6,4) ?

Comment: The first coordinate refers to the number of bar, that is, `(1,2)` means that the first bar has height two. And so on. Those values for second coordinate was just to exemplify.